# Unable to boot after boot repair using live usb

Tags: boot, 16.04, boot-repair

After a kernel update in ubuntu 16.04 system, I restarted and unable to login. It says No bootable disc found. So i repaired the boot using boot-repair. If the live usb stick is connected, ubuntu is listed in the boot options. Even though I logged in using that entry I am unable to connect internet. Ubuntu boot entry is not appearing if the live usb is removed.

Here is the report
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ybKpfGRMbK/
Can someone look into the report and help me solving the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You normally have an ESP - efi system partition on same drive as install. But your only ESP is on sde, so Boot-Repair installed grub2's UEFI boot files into the ESP on sde. You might want to add an ESP to sda, FAT32 with boot/esp flags and 300 to 500MB with gparted from live installer. And then reinstall grub again with Boot-Repair.

Comment: Thanks oldfred. With UEFI and secure boot on and legacy off, I created the EFI system partition and using gparted and then did boot repair. Now the system is booting upto the splash screen and stuck with black screen with underscore blinking at the top left corner.

Comment: Then with UEFI and secure boot off and legacy on, I deleted the EFI system partition and created Bios boot partition and did the boot repair. The boot repair message said that "The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode". Now I could able to login to the system. Everything is back but no ethernet connection.

Comment: I remember that the system was with secure boot enabled with UEFI, because sometimes after software updates, a dialog box with title Configuring secure boot appears. Now how to make it boot in UEFI mode? Shall I try with UEFI on and secure boot off and create ESP with gparted and do the boot repair? Can we have both ESP and BIOS boot partitions in a same hard disk?

Comment: I used bios_grub partition & gpt with my old BIOS only system. Then when planning new UEFI system I added both ESP & bios_grub to every new drive. So I still have some with both partitions. You need an ESP for UEFI boot or bios_grub for BIOS. But only difference then is which version of grub is installed (some settings that the grub install changes). I now only use gpt and have an ESP as first partition on every drive, even data drives, so I can put an install on it later if desired. But Ubiquity only uses the first ESP it finds.